# Move cursor to center of some selected geometry/faces

Tags: edit-mode, 3d-cursor

I am making a gun. What I'd like the to do is this

1. Select all the faces that make up the handle
2. Move the 3D cursor to the center of the selection (or center of mass)
3. Set the origin of the object at the location of the 3D cursor

I can do 1 and 3 but I'm stuck at 2.

Thanks!

Comment: related: http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/43314/positioning-the-pivot-point-in-center-in-part-of-mesh/43317#43317

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change pivot or local origin of an object](http://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object)

Answer (score 38, accepted):

In Edit Mode

Select the faces.

Press <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> and select **cursor to selected**, that will put the cursor at the center of the selected faces.

Switch to Object mode (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

Select Object>Transform>Origin to 3D cursor (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>C</kbd>).

[image]

For 2.8 there is no keyboard shortcut. Use the menu **Object** > **Set Origin**.

Comment: Thanks that does it, not sure how I managed to miss that since I was already aware of Shift+S

Comment: @cegaton Ctrl+Shift+Alt+C doesn't work anymore with Blender 2.80.

Answer (score 8):

All you have to do is <kbd>SHIFT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> then <kbd>U</kbd>. 
[image: yes sir] 
This will work in object mode and edit mode.

### Related:

https://www.blender.org/manual/editors/3dview/3d_cursor.html?highlight=cursor#using-the-snap-menu

Answer (score 4):

In Blender 2.8 - Object / Set Origin... / Origin to Center of Mass.

[image]

Comment: In a case of a cube how to I move the whole cube up and set the origin as the center of a face (e.g. the bottom face) while keeping the origin at the center of the coordinate system.

Comment: @Zingam Select the single verts in edit mode where you expect the center you whish to place the origin. Then `shift+s`  and use `Cursor to selected`. The cursor will place exact in the center of your selected verts. Then leave edit mode (`tab`) and use `object/set origin/origin to 3D cursor`.