# place bone-armature given selection of faces/vertices/edges for cursor

Tags: bones

I am trying to place a bone in an exact position on my 3d model. I need to use other geometries as references such that the desired position of the bone can be inferred from the selection of vertices/edges/faces. I have been trying to follow these 2 other answers to move the base of my bone.

[Change pivot or local origin of an object](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1291/change-pivot-or-local-origin-of-an-object)

[Move cursor to center of some selected geometry/faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60510/move-cursor-to-center-of-some-selected-geometry-faces?noredirect=1&lq=1)

My issue is that I have to "Enter Edit mode" and then select the desired vertices/edges/faces, but they do not specify *which* object needs to be in edit mode, the bone or the object(s) with the reference geometry. Also, I find that the only way to see all of the geometry at once is in wire-frame mode, but then I am unable to select the faces. In short, I do not know how to apply the answers above in the context of my question.

The bone seen below needs to have its base placed such that it is in the middle of the block model (around where the green Y-Axis is) and the Z-X plane (Blue-red arrow plane, only red line can be seen) location should be coincident with the hole for the lever. If looking along the green axis (centered) at the big block, the base of the bone would be right in the middle of the block. If looking directly into the hole, the bone base would be centered on the center of the hole. Does this make sense?
(Ignore the holes on top of the big block. Only looking at the hole near the lever/leg peg)
[image]

Comment: If you are selecting a face / edge / vert  then the mesh will need to be in edit mode. eg select a face, shift-S cursor to selected, moves cursor to face.  Exit edit mode of mesh, go into edit mode of armature select bone and shift-S snap selection to cursor.  (the snap options are pretty intuitive)

Comment: well, it appears that was the trick to get the base of the bone placed where I expected it to be. I just tried this, and it turns out that, for using multiple meshes, you simply go to object mode, shift select the objects, then click edit mode, then follow the process as described by @batFINGER I will consider this answered, even though an answer was not entered.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The user @batFINGER solved my problem:

"If you are selecting a face / edge / vert then the mesh will need to be in edit mode. eg select a face, shift-S cursor to selected, moves cursor to face. Exit edit mode of mesh, go into edit mode of armature select bone and shift-S snap selection to cursor. (the snap options are pretty intuitive)"

There are special selection tools available when you use the Shift-S hotkey that enable the fine-comb control required to move the 3d cursor to place objects.