# Move image plane from it's midpoint to grid

Tags: snapping, 3d-cursor

I'm very much new to blender transitioning from Maya.  Going through tutorials and docs.  Can't seem to get an answer for this.

I created an image plane by dragging my image into my viewport.  I want to snap the bottom center edge of my plane to the origin.  Is there a way to place my 3D cursor exactly in the middle of that bottom edge of my image plane so that I can move it from that point to the grid?

What I've tried:

1. enabled snap, edge center.
2. Shift + rmb to edit 3d cursor
3. G to move around
   but it's not snapping to anything?

I also tried Shift + S while 3d cursor is active, but still not sure how to get it to snap to the location I'd like.

Any help on this would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move cursor to center of some selected geometry/faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60510/move-cursor-to-center-of-some-selected-geometry-faces)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Keep image offset to 0. And then you can press `G` (default: Move) to snap
[image]

Open the snap before move or press ctrl after move
[image]

Fix the rotation in N-panel
[image]

Snap option
[image]

### If you want snap to 3d cursor:

Object > Snap > Selection to Cursor
[image]

Comment: Hi, thank you for the detailed response.  Very helpful.  That sort of answers my issue.  But rather than snap from the corner vert of the image plane to the corner of the box, I'd like to snap from the middle-bottom of the image plane to the corner of that box.  Is that possible?

Comment: Yes, it is possible, just set the Offset X to -0.5

Comment: Ah, so simple!  That worked.  Thank you so much!