# How do you change local axis?

Tags: axis

I am fresh off Maya and something I really liked about it was being able to change the local axis of an object to different parts of it. I really want to set the axis in one of my verts since the object is a wall that is supposed to connect with other wall pieces when placed in UE. Basically i want to move the axis from the middle of its body down to its far corner vertex. How do i do that?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Move cursor to center of some selected geometry/faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60510/move-cursor-to-center-of-some-selected-geometry-faces)

Answer (score 1):

You can move object's origin with all transform tools when you enable Affect Only: 'Origins' in (Object-Mode) Header > Options or Tool Properties tab in the Properties Editor:

[image]

This way you can transform the origin of object space and object space itself any way you wish using all transform functionality including snapping, numerical input and all other tricks you can think of.

Answer (score 0):

(okay so I was given an answer that was half of what I wanted. So to make sure I get it and to make sure anyone with the same question gets it I will explain what I did). From what I can tell the best way to get this is to take the cursor and then whit Snap selected to Vertex you can move the cursor to the the vertex you want. From there all you gotta do is follow the instructions given by ppl on here [Move cursor to center of some selected geometry/faces](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/60510/move-cursor-to-center-of-some-selected-geometry-faces) .
If that is the best version then thank you very much for the hint.

Comment: I think it's called "Pivot Point" in Maya, but it is "Origin" in Blender. ["Pivot Point"](https://i.imgur.com/rSDUYxO.png) in Blender defines the origin for transform operations while object space has origin that is a separate thing. I don't remember exactly how it is done in Maya, but you don't necessarily need to modify object space in order to change transform pivot or transform orientation in Blender.