# How can i center axis on the object?

Tags: modeling, edit-mode

[image]

How to center the axis(yellow) on my object(blue)?

Comment: See also: https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/43317/1853

Answer (score 1):

Option 1:

1. Select your object (not edit mode)
2. Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> (Yes, 4 keys at once)
3. Select "Origin to Geometry"

Option 2:

1. Select your object and go into edit mode
2. Press <kbd>A</kbd> (maybe twice) to select your whole mesh.
3. Press <kbd>G</kbd> to grab your selection and move it to your Origin.
4. (If you only want to move it straight down press <kbd>Z</kbd> to stick the movement to the Z-axis

Note that if you want to move your object around in your scene you should not do that in edit mode as the origin (the thing in the yellow circle) doesn't move with it. Otherwise you end up with the problem you hae right now.

Comment: So if i want to adjust an object i should do it in edit mode but changing the position should be done in Object mode?

Comment: Generelly speaking: Yes.
The origin of an object ist the small orange dot. That is by default also the pivot point if you rotate it for example. 
Just try it out yourself: If you move an object in edit mode the origin stays at the same place and does not move with it. If you move an object in object mode the origin moves with it. That is what you want most of the time.